# confidence intervals for GLMER model

Tags: confidence-interval, lme4-nlme

I'm  trying to calculate confidence intervals for GLMER model. I heard that there are two ways I could do it:

Number 1: 
exp(Estimate Std + 1.96 * Std Error) 
exp(ES - 1.96* Std Error)

Number 2:
m<-confint(model, 'IV', level=0.95)

However, the functions give me different results.   Can anybody please explain why I get different results? Which one should I be using?